# Unicode codepoint of the format \Unnnnnnnn

Tags: c, unicode

In C, I discovered that there are two unicode escape sequences `\u` and `\U`

```
\u takes the format - \unnnn
\u takes the format - \Unnnnnnnn
```

For example this program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Unicode character for snowman : \u2603");
    printf("Trying for a valid U+nnnnnnn character : \U10FFFF"); /* this will be an error as it needs U+nnnnnnnn */
}
```

Prints the valid unicode for the first one. But I can't find a codepoint suitable in the format U+nnnnnnnn

Can you explain what this 32 bit (?) Unicode code point should represent? Point me to a valid character like snowman?

Comment: `0x10FFFFFF` is not a valid code point. The greatest currrently valid Unicode codepoint is `0x10FFFF`. (A good compiler should have told you that.)

Comment: @KerrekSB - Thanks. Then what is a valid value for U+nnnnnnnn ?

Comment: Note that you must have exactly 4 hex digits after `\u` and exactly 8 hex digits after `\U`, and the first 2 of the 8 must be 0 to have a chance of being a valid Unicode character. `\U0010FFFF` is the maximum Unicode code point, though it actually is defined as an invalid character (as is `\U00xxFFFF` for any value of xx).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for answering. It is interesting that first two of the 8 must be 0 to have a chance of being a valid Unicode. I wonder it was designed so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\unnnn` can only be used for characters in the "Basic Multilingual Plane" (i.e.
up to U+FFFF), whereas `\Unnnnnnnn` can express *all* possible Unicode characters.

For example

```
printf("Unicode character MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF : \U0001D11E\n");
```

produces

```
Unicode character MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF :
```

(if that character is present in the font used by your terminal).

You can find tables for all Unicode characters
at http://unicode.org. A complete list is http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt.

Comment: `\Unnnnnnnn` can also be used for characters within the BMP. For example, the "SNOWMAN" character can be written either as `\u2603` or as `\U00002603` (though there's probably no good reason to use the latter, unless it's for symmetry in a list containing other non-BMP characters).

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `\U` for things *in* the BMP, such as `\U00000041`.

Comment: Yes, you are both right. What I meant is that you need `\Unnnnnnnn` for those characters. I will try to improve the wording ....

Comment: Thank you all for answer and clarifying this one!.